# Why my excel is corrupt when adding data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

This code is supposed to add "ABC" in B3, but when writing the document, its size goes to 0ko (original is ~200ko) and Excel refuse to open it up.

```
const excel = require("exceljs");

const modele = "./myexcel.xlsx"

var workbook = new excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile(modele)
.then(function() {
    var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Personnel');

    worksheet.getCell('B3').value = "ABC";
    
    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile(modele)

});
```

I don't want to create a new sheet but to write in an existing one

I tried using stream, writing in a new file and different version of this code but it doesn't seems to work.

I've used ExcelJS before for the same purpose and it worked.

The cell B3 is in a table I want to add a lot of data in.

The sheet looks like this :

[image: the sheet looks like this]

*Versions :*

- Exceljs 4.3.0
- Node 16.14.2
- NWjs 0.63.1
- Windows 10 pro 10.0.19045

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with node-webkit…

Comment: @sysrage the javascript is run in a node-webkit application, not knowing where the bug come from I added it in the tag

Comment: Your code looks good, I was able to run it with a 4MB file with no problems. Could you share your version of exceljs and node? [This issue](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/523) seems related, but it's from years ago. Possible that you're using an outdated version

Comment: Thank you @rpm for the help, I checked it seems not to be the problem :/ exceljs is 4.3.0 and node is 16.14.2 but the file is runned using [NodeWebkit](https://nwjs.io/). I also got no error in console when running the code.

Comment: are you sure the excel file is not corrupt or something? can you open the excel file save it again? then run through this code?

Comment: What is your Operating System? It should not cause such error, but who knows whether or not the issue comes from there

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I deleted it and open the original again, made Save As > modele.xlsx where it is supposed to be and it still corrupt the result.

Comment: @EduardoPoço i'm on windows 10.0.19045 pro. You're right, it can come from everything.

Comment: Can you update the question with the full js code? Also, have you tested it on an empty excel file with a blank sheet called 'Personnel'? I would like to know if the error happens again

Comment: with a blank sheet it works @EduardoPoço ! Don't know why it doesn't work on a pre-made table. This is the full code i'm using

Comment: That's because the 'excel' variable is not defined there. Are you loading ExcelJS in another module? And, maybe, the original file is corrupted before the data being added, as a blank one gets filled correctly

Comment: @EduardoPoço I edited the question to include the exceljs declaration (it was already present in my code). The file is not corrupted as I can edit in data and a "Save As" didn't allow me to insert data via ExcelJS

Comment: I see from the picture that you are using filters in your worksheet. Maybe, some Excel instructions must run after the value is set and you need to wait a little before closing the file. Are you quitting the program just after running the function that writes to the file? Try to clear the filters before saving the Excel file that will be modified.

Comment: @EduardoPoço the filters are already clean and i waited 10 minutes before closing the program. The excel file stays at 0kb

Comment: Wow... Beats me, no idea this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was because this was an Excel table.

[There's the documentation](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#tables) to use the table with ExcelJS and should have used `table.addRow()` to add data in the table

I just edited my file to remove the table and it also works.